# iTerm2: How to rearrange split panes from horizontal orientation to vertical

Tags: iterm

If you have a window with two panes side-by-side (i.e. one pane to the left, the other pane to the right), is it possible to change the orientation so that one pane is above the other (without closing any of the panes)?

I cannot for the life of me find it among the key bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. click on the pane header
   [image]
2. drag to the desired position (in this case, to the bottom)
   [image]
3. drop the pane at will
   [image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Grab one pane's header bar and drag it over the over the other pane. The UI will show what will happen. Let go when you have the desired configuration.

In the screenshot I've dragged the right pane over the left, the red box shows where the right pane will move to. The result will be the window split horizontally.

[image]